# Why can't customize sshd log info as sshd.log?

Tags: logs, sshd, rsyslog

My os info:

```
cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.32-042stab127.2 (root@kbuild-rh6-x64.eng.sw.ru) (gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu Jan 4 16:41:44 MSK 2018
```

I want to customize sshd log into a specified file--/var/log/sshd.log.

```
vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
SyslogFacility local0

vim /etc/rsyslog.conf 
local0.*    /var/log/sshd.log

systemctl restart sshd
systemctl restart rsyslog
```

Login in the vps with ssd.
cat /var/log/sshd.log

Nothing in /var/log/sshd.log.
How to customize sshd log info as  sshd.log

Comment: It used to be - maybe still is - that syslog won't write to a file that doesn't exist; try `touch /var/log/sshd.log`